# FQL Query for getting the data about a product page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have been trying to check with all the links available in the internet to give me the posts and details of the users for a particular product page (here it is "fitbit")

Can some one give me a query to fetch the data from https://www.facebook.com/fitbit?fref=ts page, my basic need is to get the updates and user comments from the page and use it for sentiment analysis. If you could redirect me to some links which can help me with the Sentiment analysis of a product through Facebook data it'll be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Stream and Page Tables through FQL. To get information about the page you can use a query like this:

```
$fql = 'SELECT fan_count,page_id,talking_about_count from page WHERE   type="Product/Service" AND name="Fitbit" LIMIT 1';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql));
```

To get the posts on a page:

```
$Posts = 'SELECT created_time,message,like_info from stream WHERE source_id=123 LIMIT 50';
$ret_Posts = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $Posts));
```

You can visit the following link for more information https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/